# Plot histogram for feature of array with known and limited values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

A column called "pets" in my dataframe is basically a feature of pets list:

```
["dog"]  
["dog", "cat"]  
["cat", "parrot"]  
["dog", "cat", "fish"]
```

possible pets: `["dog", "cat", "parrot", "fish"]`

I want to plot an histogram of the column so that each pet in a feature values list is counted for each pet.
In this case:

```
#dog = 3  
#cat = 2  
#parrot = 1  
#fish = 1
```

How is it done?

I think it's possible to flatten the feature to 4 boolean features, then plot these, however it doesn't seem as the "right" solution.

```py
df['pets'].head()
--
0   ["dog"]  
1   ["dog", "cat"]  
2   ["cat", "parrot"]  
3   ["dog", "cat", "fish"]  
Name: pets, dtype: object
```

I want each column in the histogram to count all pets so that the total size of the histogram (sum of heights/counts) is possible to be larger than the number of entries (in the example above, there are 4 entries, yet the size of the histogram should be 1+2+2+3 = 8

---

Edit: Is it right / possible to repeat certain entries, or flatten these entries to gain single value feature?
For example, the above will turn into:

```
df['pets'].head()
--
0   "dog"  
1   "dog"
2   "cat"  
3   "cat"  
4   "parrot"    
5   "dog"  
6   "cat"  
7   "fish"  
Name: pets, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need flattening values, then [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and plot by [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
import ast

s = pd.Series([z for y in df['col'] for z in y])
#if necessary convert to lists from strings 
#s = pd.Series([z for y in df['col'] for z in ast.literal_eval(y)])
print (s)
0       dog
1       dog
2       cat
3       cat
4    parrot
5       dog
6       cat
7      fish
dtype: object

s.value_counts().plot.bar()
```

EDIT: If there is multiple columns is necessary repeat another columns values, so first create DataFrame, reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
print (df)
                       col   A
0                  ["dog"]   3
1          ["dog", "cat"]    7
2        ["cat", "parrot"]  10
3  ["dog", "cat", "fish"]    2

import ast

a = (pd.DataFrame(df.pop('col').apply(ast.literal_eval).values.tolist())
       .stack()
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .rename('col'))
print (a)

0       dog
1       dog
1       cat
2       cat
2    parrot
3       dog
3       cat
3      fish
Name: col, dtype: object
```

---

```
df = df.join(a).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    A     col
0   3     dog
1   7     dog
2   7     cat
3  10     cat
4  10  parrot
5   2     dog
6   2     cat
7   2    fish
```

Then is possible use:

```
df['col'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

Comment: Thankyou! that works great for plotting the histogram!  
Yet, I wish to use these entries later on to find correlations with other columns, so placing these in the original dataframe is necessary in this case.

Comment: @Jes - `ast.literal_eval` was necessary?